# how to issue invoice automatically to the user in razorpay if payment is completed

Tags: python, django, razorpay

I am using razorpay as the payment gateway for my django application.When a payment is completed,I want to create invoice automatically with invoice number and GST details and send invoice  to the customer through email.[Here](https://razorpay.com/docs/invoices/operations/#creating-an-invoice)  I found only manual method to create invoice.Is there any possible way to create invoice automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code or call api for creating invoices once the event "Payment.captured" event takes place. Razorpay will send webhook to your server. Once the payment is successful they will send "payment.captured" webhook. Do your code accordingly.